# Why does English have words from Latin and none from Celtic?

Tags: english, history, borrowing

It is known that Britain's history of invasion goes as: Celtic arrival, Roman domination, Saxon settlement, Nordic settlement, Norman invasion.
If England's identity was largely made from the Saxons (eventually Anglo-Saxons), and there are almost no Celtic words left besides proper nouns, how come there is a significant number of English words that came from Latin, even after excluding borrowings and loanwords from French, if the Saxons and Vikings supposedly overrode any culture there?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you mean. Nearly all Latin borrowings in modern English were borrowed _after_ the Norman invasion, most of them from the 14th century onwards. Latin loan words preceding Anglo-Saxon times are very rare indeed.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Wiktionary has a category that includes [72 words supposed to be borrowed from Latin to OE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Old_English_terms_borrowed_from_Latin), which is not a lot but not negligible.

Comment: @ewawe Most of those are from Anglo-Saxon times (i.e., they were borrowed from Latin into Old English). If I’m understanding the question here correctly, William would have expected more words to remain from when the Romans were in charge before the Angles and Saxons and whatnots came to Britain, and there are indeed very few of those. There are more, though still not all that many, from Old English, but Middle English is where it really took off.

Comment: Old English was mostly spoken and written by Christians, who also wrote and prayed in Latin. And Christian terms were often borrowed instead of calqued.

Comment: Take a look at this http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cpercy/courses/6361Lovis.htm

Comment: The general consensus is that, as Richard Hogg (Hogg 2002) sums it up nicely, "the Celtic peoples formed a **subordinate** group within the new Anglo-Saxon society, and hence **their language was shunned**" [emphasis mine - Alex B.]. I wouldn't say "none" though - see e.g. Durkin 2014, Part II.5 Old English in contact with Celtic

Comment: My favorite examples of Celtic loanwords in English are **car** and **slogan**.

Comment: @AlexB. Huh, I did not know that _slogan_ is from _sluagh-ghairm_. Very nifty!

Comment: "significant number of English words that came from Latin, even after excluding borrowings and loanwords from French": which words did you have in mind?  Can you give an example of such a word that came from Latin but did not come from French?  The words I can think of in that category came even later on, not earlier.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am thinking of compendium for example. It seems to be neither French nor borrowed, Google and other sources say it comes straight from Latin. I am interested in how it came from Latin.

Comment: @William https://blog.oup.com/2016/03/latin-renaissance-world-language/

Comment: @William Many online dictionaries will tell you that. _Compendium_ was borrowed from Latin and is first attested around 1575–85.

Comment: Yes, I said along those lines in the comment to the answer below, and it seems that the answer to my question is 'those words came from Medieval Latin'. Maybe I will bring my own answer if I have the time and motivation.

Comment: How about the second part of the question: "why none from Celtic?" Is this indeed so and if so , why ?

Comment: [Lists of English words of Celtic origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_words_of_Celtic_origin)

Comment: @my2cts see my comments above

Comment: @my2cts Romans imposed their “civilized” way of life as they conquered territories. Though they allocated thousands of men and built some infrastructure, their influence wasn’t so strong, so the Anglo-Saxons overrode the culture there and imposed their language. There was two levels, Romans pushing the Celts away, the Saxons then imposing their culture but keeping Catholicism. There are good sources in Spanish and Italian (few good ones in Portuguese), most British sources funnily put much emphasis on the Celts being warded off and Saxons being kicked out of the island until the Romans left.

Comment: It's also considerable that the Celtic layer is the oldest and would thus have the longest time to naturalize to the point that influences cannot be reasonably seperated from the rest of the language by modern scholarship. Thus the influence of Celtic onto English, e.g. with regards to grammar, and West-Germanic with regards to lexical *do be* all but (or *albeit*) uncertain, as much as the history of that time is certainly not well documented.

Comment: @AlexB. , isn't "car" from anglo-norman "*carre*"?

Comment: @ErgativeMan Did you read the etymology section in the OED entry until the very end? It's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the Middle Ages, Latin was the language of scholarship throughout Europe.  Many Medieval Latin words were imported directly into English, either to express concepts that had no exact English equivalent, or to show that the writer/speaker knew Latin and was therefore a learned scholar and presumably authoritative.

Comment: This is the right answer that I ended up figuring out by myself. Thanks for putting it here. The others mostly miss the point and you even get a downvote; this site has really been crumbling down.

Answer (score 10):

As jk says, there are very few Latin loans in English *from pre-Saxon times*. English does have quite a lot of words borrowed from Latin and Romance, but the vast majority of them come from well after the Saxon invasion.

It's worth noting also that there was a lot of contact between Latin/Romance and Germanic all throughout Europe. When we see Latin words attested from Anglo-Saxon times, it's likely that they were borrowed into Saxon before the invasion, rather than persisting from the Latin spoken by Roman colonists.

Comment: I like the second paragraph a lot. It would be nice if you could add some examples if possible. Also, it doesn't answer the question, but misunderstands its premise. I asked why there are so many Latin words, not whether they came from pre-Saxon or not. I did some research and it seems that a lot of Latin words, many ending with '-um', came from Medieval Latin instead.

Answer (score 4):

Some Latin loans in Anglo-Saxon are really old borrowings that were acquired by the West Germanic speakers from the Romans on the continent (*fenester* "window", modern German *Fenster* belongs into this category), other were introduced by Christian missionaries. Since anything Christian was foreign to the Anglo-Saxons they used a lot of borrowed words for religious terminology. I have also heard (but no hard reference on this) that the Christian missionaries deliberately replaced a lot of the heathen religious vocabulary with foreign terms in order to cut the old traditions off.

I'd be very interested in hearing of any words except place names that were borrowed from [British Vulgar Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Latin).

Comment: (Part of)The question actually reads - *why there are none from Celtic?*

Comment: I was concentrating on the last sentence of the question "how come there is a significant number of English words that came from Latin, even after excluding borrowings and loanwords from French, if the Saxons and Vikings supposedly overrode any culture there?" by doubting that the Anglo-Saxons borrowed from Anglo-Romance.

Comment: What is *Anglo-Romance*?

Comment: @AlexB. Searched for a better term and substituted it with "British Vulgar Latin"

Comment: The fenester quip is very interesting. In Spanish and Portuguese, and most possibly other Neo-Latins, 'defenestrar' (de+fenestr+ar) means 'to throw out of the window'.

Comment: @William "Defenestrate" means this in English, *e.g.* the [defenestrations of Prague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestrations_of_Prague).

Answer (score 0):

Because that's called Gaelic.

The Celtic cultures, and (to a lesser extent) the Celtic people, were largely pushed up into Scotland or over into Ireland.  The new settlers who displaced them were Latin-speaking Romans, then Germanic-speaking [Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles), [Saxons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxons) and [Vikings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danelaw), followed by French-speaking [Normans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normans).

For the language to adopt significant numbers of words from Celtic, there would have needed to be an overlap between the cultures (e.g. like the French-speaking Normans ruling over the Germanic-speaking Anglo-Saxons), rather than a displacement.

Incidentally, this tangentally relates to why many 'processed' foods come from French (e.g. *"Beef"*, from *"bov"*, meaning "cow"/"ox"/"cattle") - the language spoken by the Nobles, either because they were newly arrived or attempting to ingratiate themselves with the new leadership - while the name of the source plant or animal comes has German roots (e.g. *"Cow"*, from *"Kuh"*) - the language spoken by the serfs and villein.  In other words: did you work to raise it in one form, or afford to eat it in another?

Comment: The Celtic peoples in what is now England weren't Gaels, weren't pushed into Irish or Scottish territory (though they might have been pushed *out* of Scotland by Gaels, if the Picts spoke Brittonic), and didn't give up their language in favour of Latin. At the time of the Anglo-Saxon settlement, the language of England and Wales was Common Brittonic, just beginning to separate into its daughter languages.